# How to prevent delete database from console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found that would be so easily delete database from firebase console by clicking X on the root. Is there anyways we can prevent that ?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are the only one with access to your database, there is no way to disable that function, since is inbuilt with the firebase page, I would recommend to you to secure your account in order to just be you the only one that have access.

From the code you can also inflate a dialog telling if you want to erase all the database.

From the web it will prompt a dialog too but if you accidentally click and delete all you can still restore your database json with the restore backups that are made from Backups tab. Remember that you can only restore your database JSON but if you delete all your Storage folders and resources you will be not able to make a backup for that

Another thing to take in mind is that when your firebase project becomes static and stops working in a dynamic mode since the quantity of data, it will not show you the delete button for a large tree, instead it will show it for single elements inside that tree